# Openfire Xmpp - Client can not receive the message

Tags: xmpp, message, openfire, smack

I've been struggling with XMPP chatting a lot through Smack and Openfire server. My problem is as follows:

Today I put the openfire server from 3.9.3 upgrade to 4.0.2，then the client will can not receive any message,I checked the database to find information is stored in the offline data table, and need to log in again to receive the message.

For example, Whenever a user sends a message to another user, the message is received correctly at the other user. But any reply doesn't show up at the sender of the first message. So User 1 sends to User 2 successfully. User 2 is then unable to send to User 1 any reply. On the other hand, if I restart and let the users login again, User 2 can send to User 1 but not vice versa.

How I can recover this issue?

Comment: you can check my [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551229/sending-and-receiving-messages-using-smack-api-for-android/34536098#34536098)

Comment: Okay.. But am using this [code](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android/tree/master/xabber) @Devendra Singh

Comment: check your chat_created flag is properly working or not. May be falg is true and session is not creatin again

Comment: did you find solution?